# Conversion error only if not using SELECT TOP

Tags: t-sql

I have a table where the column `Col` may or may not include the string 'geb.'. When it does I want to extract the following 10 characters and convert them to `DATETIME`

Here's my query:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT
        TOP 100000000
        Col,
        CONVERT(DATETIME, SUBSTRING(Col, PATINDEX('%geb.%', Col) + 5, 10)) AS bd
    FROM
        T
    WHERE
        Col LIKE '%geb.%'
)
SELECT
    Col,
    bd
FROM
    CTE
WHERE
    bd <= '01.01.1950'
```

The above query works fine. When I omit the `TOP xxx`statement and the WHERE clause includes `bd` in ANY WAY (IS NULL, =/!= '',...) I get a conversion error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

When I include the `TOP xxx` or remove `bd` from the WHERE clause the query completes without errors.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

It is because when you don't use `TOP` clause or `WHERE` condition , you end up trying to convert some `col` values where characters following `'geb.'` can not be converted to `DateTime`

**You are filtering *non `DateTime` convertible values* from `select` list either using `TOP` or `WHERE` clause**

Use [TRY_CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql) instead like this :

```
TRY_CONVERT ( data_type [ ( length ) ], expression [, style ] )
```

Use :

```
TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME, SUBSTRING(Col, PATINDEX('%geb.%', Col) + 5, 10)) AS bd
```

Instead of :

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, SUBSTRING(Col, PATINDEX('%geb.%', Col) + 5, 10)) AS bd
```

Comment: but the query still completes when I just execute the query inside the CTE. When I remove the WHERE clause from the second select the result from CTE is the same, whether I use TOP or not

Comment: Can you try the suggested fix

Comment: This works, thanks for that, but that still doesn't answer my question. How is the resultset of select/select top any different? I'm having a look at the execution plan right now.

Comment: please refer explanation highlighted in **bold** font

Comment: Regarding your **bold** text: this seems to be the case but that still does not explain why this happens. My question remains unanswered and it would be irresponsible for me to mark your answer as valid since this would be misleading to other readers.